# I can't figure out how to restart a loop, when the person enters in a wrong input

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Ok so for an assignment I need to make a loop for the user to input a number 1-4 for either rock paper scissors or to end the game, but if they enter in anything other than those I need them to be able to re-enter the number but I can't seem to get my loop to restart or something similar...

Code (It's just my while loop

```
while(user < 5)
          {
              System.out.println("Please enter in a number");
              computer = generator.nextInt(3) + 1;            
              user = keyboardIn.nextInt();

              //tell the player what was chosen
              if(user == 1)//player is rock
              {
                 System.out.println ("Player is rock");  
              }
              else if (user == 2)//player is paper
              {
                 System.out.println ("Player is paper");
              }
              else if (user == 3) //player is scissors
              {
                System.out.println ("Player is scissors");

              }
              else if (user == 4)
              {
                  System.out.println("Thank you for playing!");
                  break;
              }
              else if (user >= 5)
              {
                  System.out.println(user + " was never an option. \nTry again.");
                  user = keyboardIn.nextInt();
              }

              //tell the player what the computer has chosen
              if(computer == 1)//computer is rock
              {
                 System.out.println ("Computer is rock");
              }
              else if (computer == 2)//computer is paper
              {
                 System.out.println ("Computer is paper");
              }
              else if (computer == 3)//computer is scissors
              {
                 System.out.println ("Computer is scissors");
              }


              //determine winner
              if (user == computer) //tie
              {
                 System.out.println("It is a tie");
              }
              else if (user < computer) //player is rock
              {
                 System.out.println("Computer wins");
              }
              else //computer is scissors
              {
                 System.out.println("Player wins");
              }
              System.out.println();
          }
```

Comment: code before will be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use `continue` to jump back to the top of the loop. Note, however, that at the top you ask for user input, and on error you do so too; that's one time too many.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
boolean gameOver = false;
while(!gameOver){
    if (user < 5){
     ....
    }
}
```

and set gameOver = true in each of your game-ending conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the part:

```
else if (user >= 5)
              {
                  System.out.println(user + " was never an option. \nTry again.");
                  user = keyboardIn.nextInt();
              }
```

With:

```
else if (user >= 5)
              {
                  System.out.println(user + " was never an option. \nTry again.");
                  continue;
              }
```

Basically the continue, brakes the current loop and start over a new one, of course verifying first the condition...

However if you want your code to be a little bit more efficient, in your specific case this would be my way of doing it:

```
while(true) {
    computer = generator.nextInt(3) + 1; 
    do {
        System.out.println("Please enter in a number");           
        user = keyboardIn.nextInt();
    } while(user>=5 && user<=0);
    //The rest of your code deleting also the last else if statement
 }
```

This way your code is cleaner and more maintainable. Plus you will be sure that after the code exit from the loop you will definitely have a number between 0 and 4 which would be a valid option